# ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable while trying to run npm install, on a cloned repo using windows 10

Tags: python, node.js, npm

I just started a tutorial on node at udacity, I cloned the sample project from git as directed by the instructor, then I ran the `npm install` command, then I encountered these errors

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr>npm install
> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\bufferutil`
gyp ERR! node -v v8.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok

utf-8-validate@1.2.2 install C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\utf-8-validate
node-gyp rebuild


C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ogbonna Vitalis Pc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\nodejs\offlineweb\wittr\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v8.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I already have a working python IDE om my system, which I ticked ADD PYTHON TO PATH while installing it. I have tried googling around but no positive results yet.
Please your suggestions will be appreciated..

Comment: run python in your command prompt . Is python install ?  If not add python path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed python version 2.7, I ticked add path to env variable and that solved my problem